# Create a string composed of blanks (_) and spaces based on another string

Tags: c++, string

I am so very close to finishing an assignment, where I was instructed to create a wheel of fortune game.

The last thing I need to do is, to get the **game board** to print the correct number of **spaces** and **dashes** for letters not guessed yet.

The user inputs a string in the beginning of the game, let's say it is `"Hello World"`

I want this function to create a new `string`, that would be `"-----  -----"`.

I thought, what I have would work, but when I try to compile, I get invalid conversion from `const char*` to `char`.

Here, is what I have: `secret` is the `string` the user has given as input for the game, `guess` is a letter that a player guessed, `hidden` is the new string with dashes and spaces that I'm trying to create.

```
void show_board(string &guess, string &secret, string &hidden)
{
   for(int q=0; q < secret.length ; q++)
   {
      if(secret.at(q) == " ")
      {
         hidden.at(q) == " ";
      }
      else
      {
         hidden.at(q) == "-";
      }
   }
}
```

I just realized, that the `if` part is really redundant, but my question still remains.

So for the `for` loop I now have:

```
for(int q=0 ; q < secret.length() ; q++)
{
   if(secret[q]==' ')
   {
      hidden += " ";
   }
   else if(guess == secret[q])
   {
      hidden += guess;
   }
   else
   {
      hidden += "-";
   }
}
```

And, I am getting an error on the line with `guess`, that says:

> error no match for 'operator==' in 'guess == ((std::string*)secret)->std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator[] [with _CharT = char, _traits = std::char_traits, _Alloc = std::allocator](((long unsigned int)q))'

Comment: You are missing a `)` in `show_board` function header.

Comment: And a semi-colon after your else stmt.

Comment: Can you give an example, using variables `guess`, `secret` and `hidden`, of how this is supposed to work?

Comment: you might want to consider using RegEx replacement (see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_replace/). If I see correctly, you would replace anything not " " to "-". (Seems more clear and way shorter to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question, does not specify how `guess` should be used, so, I have corrected the function `show_board` to create for e.g. `"----- -----"` from `"hello world"` using `hidden` and `secret` respectively.

Here is the code:

```
void show_board(string &guess, string &secret, string &hidden)
{
   hidden = "";

   for(int q=0; q < secret.length ; q++)
   {
      if(secret[q] == ' ')
      {
         hidden += " ";
      }
      else if(secret[q] == guess[0]) // assuming guess.length == 1
      {
         hidden += guess;
      }
      else
      {
         hidden += "-";
      }
   }
}
```

Here, the `+=` operator when used with `string` data type, gives the functionality of **concatenation**.

Also, the `[index]` operator, gives then `char` from the `string` at a given `index`, hence comparison with `' '`, which is a `char`, should be used instead of `" "`.

**Note:** Here, no track of how many characters have been guessed yet, is being kept.

**Edit:**

To solve the problem in the note above, I suggest that you create a separate `initialize_hidden` function to generate the `hidden` string first, and then use that `hidden` string for all subsequent guesses, using the `show_board` function like:

```
void initialize_hidden(string &secret, string &hidden) // to do something like generating "----- -----" from "hello world" for the first time.
{
   hidden = "";

   for(int q=0; q < secret.length ; q++)
   {
      if(secret[q] == ' ')
      {
         hidden += " ";
      }
      else
      {
         hidden += "-";
      }
   }
}

void show_board(string &guess, string &secret, string &hidden) // assumming that: hidden == "----- -----" has been initialized using initialize_hidden before and it could also be: hidden == "-e--o -o---" for wubsequent guesses
{
   for(int q=0; q < secret.length; q++)
   {
      if(secret[q] == guess[0]) // assuming guess.length == 1
      {
         hidden[q] = guess[0]; // just replace the newly guessed character, because rest(' 's and '-'s) would already be present since, initialize_hidden has been already called once.
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Okay all works now say the user guesses h so guess = h.  Can I add an 'else if(guess==secret[q])' then add guess at q?

Comment: That would be for a single character guess. How do you expect to maintain the state of the previously guessed characters, when the player tries to guess another character? This is not possible, using the current implementation, because `hidden` gets initialized to `""` empty `string` every time `show_board` gets called? I suggest that you create a separate initializer function to generate the `hidden` string first and then use that `hidden` string for all subsequent guesses using the `show_board` function.

Comment: Okay I see what you are saying and I may have to do the other function but why am I getting this error? (check original post)

Comment: See that, I have edited my answer, to make that work.

Comment: What if guess is a char?

Comment: That, would be even better. Then, `secret[q] == guess` would work. From the beginning I was not getting the point of declaring `guess` as a `string`, it should have been a `char` in the first place. It is just that, I did not want to change your function prototype.

Comment: Yeah it was a char all along I made a mistake in the parameters. Sorry about the confusion and thank you for all your help.

Comment: Happy to help! Welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419).

Comment: So if I am going to do another similar function to be able to hold the modified hidden message like you were pointing out earlier how would I do this without initializing hidden to ""??

Answer (score 1):

Try switching your double quotes to single quotes.  Double quotes are for string literals, but you're comparing to characters in this case.

Comment: Okay it compiles now but when the function gets called the core is dumped and it says: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'       what(): basic_string::at        Abort (core dumped)

Comment: What line is throwing this exception?  I'm guessing you initialized an empty string or something like that.

Comment: Make sure those input strings are not empty.

Comment: I don't think, you have understood the question of the OP well, before posting an answer. Your answer simply corrects errors in the syntax and misses those in the logic of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of inputs here :

1. hidden.at(q) == "-" . This is actually comparison and not assignment and then "" is used for strings and not characters. May be, modify the code as : hidden.at(q) = '-'
2. std::string.at(x) gives you const_char and you are assigning non-const value ('-') to it. A type casting is required (  )
3. Try restricting the looping of your string with std::string::npos

Hope these help.

Comment: I don't think, you have understood the question of the OP well, before posting an answer. Your answer simply corrects errors in the syntax and misses those in the logic of the program.